# Vue 2: Template not rendering properly

Tags: vue.js, components, vuejs2

I have a component:

```
Vue.component('repo-button', {
    template: "<div class='socialCircle-item success'><i class='fa fa-comment show_repo' data-check_in='{{ check_in_id }}' data-repo='{{ repo_id }}'</i></div>"
});
```

and am trying to render it using the following:

```
<repo-button repo_id="8" check_in_id="30"></repo-button>
```

but in my view I see the following:

```
<div class="socialCircle-item success" repo_id="8" check_in_id="30"></div>
```

My `<i></i>` element is no longer there... how else am I supposed to render this?

Comment: You left the closing angle bracket for `<i>`. Also, you should likely use the binding syntax.

Comment: sheeeesh.  Thanks for catching that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I additionally added the prop definitions you would typically use for a component.

```
Vue.component('repo-button', {
  props:["check_in_id", "repo_id"],
  template: `
    <div class='socialCircle-item success'>
      <i class='fa fa-comment show_repo' 
         :data-check_in='check_in_id' 
         :data-repo='repo_id'></i>
    </div>`
});
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/EWMKxP?editors=1010).